# Grails PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter throws NPE

Tags: rest, grails, caching, nullpointerexception

I've a REST controller that I'm posting JSON data to. Unit test works fine but when data is posted from the browser, I get a NPE. Opened bug [GRAILS-11860](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11860) but don't think they'll get to it soon, if they ever do (some bugs are open for years), so figured may've better luck asking here.

**Steps to reproduce**

- Clone branch grails-bugs with `git clone -b grails-bugs --single-branch https://github.com/abhijitsarkar/grails.git`
- `cd movie-directory`
- `grails run-app`
- From a browser `http://localhost:8080/movie-database/movies/create`
- Put in anything in the text box and click create.

Seems similar to bug <s>[GRAILS-10402](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10402)</s> that was apparently fixed in `2.3-RC2` (huh?). Disabling cache by putting `grails.cache.enabled = false` in `Config.groovy` still throws NPE from `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Check which Controller Action the create invokes when the form is submitted.  Does it try to render to a .gsp view that does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Just resolved this error by fixing an error in the naming between a view and a controller method.  The controller had `def createUser()`, which did a `render(view: 'createNewUser')`. So far, so good. The form served and you could fill it out.  But, see how the controller method name and .gsp name do not match `(def createUser != createNewUser.gsp)` Then, the submit action of the form went to a `def saveUser()`, which tried to do a `render view: 'createUser'`, which did not exist as a .gsp file, resulting in the NPE

Comment: Thanks but after a year, I no longer have the inclination to deal with Grails c*ap. The bug I opened was one of more than 6 and still open. Good luck to those who are using Grails. Luckily, most of us have other choices.

Comment: Thank for the good luck, and thanks for your opinion. For what Grails buys me, I can deal with some issues like this. Luckily for me, I can get through them pretty quick. And, I've yet to meet a platform that didn't have some of these sorts of odd issues, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a web application without database connection. I had completely removed the `DataSource.groovy` file but some of my services and controllers were still marked as transactional. When there is no database around, there is no transaction manager present that can handle transactions. When I removed the transactional markers, it worked fine.

See this blog-post: [Using Grails without a database](http://digitalbreed.com/2011/using-grails-without-a-database)

It is still quite an ugly error message to get a NPE so I would still consider it to be a bug in Grails.